# Kentico - Transformation Eval() & trailing space at the end

Tags: kentico

This must be the simplest question ever, but again, I don't know the answer. I've just noticed that (in my case) using something like Eval("Location") always creates a trailing blank space at the end of the output. Normally I don't care about that trailing space, but in one particular situation, it has to be removed. I've tried using replace() but that only works for the text itself but not the trailing blank space, such as "San Francisco  " becomes "SanFrancisco  ", but the trailing space still exists. Please let me know how to get rid of it. I've checked my text, and it doesn't have any space at the end.

```
Eval("Location").ToString().Replace(" ","")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is .Trim() which will remove both trailing and leading blank spaces from a string. So you can use

```
Eval("Location").ToString().Trim()
```

However, if using .Replace() isn't removing that trailing space, then I would say the space is not coming from the field itself, but rather from something after it in the transformation.

If your code is like: 
`"<%#Eval("Location").ToString().Trim()%> [other content]"` then there will always be a space between that field content and the rest of the content. Perhaps check the transformation and see if there is a space after you are evaluating that field?

Comment: Actually, I did try both Trim() and Replace(). it looks like that space is not part of the string

Comment: Since you've mentioned [other content], although I don't have it, it helped. I tested <%# Eval("Location")%><%# Eval("Location2")%> on one line, then there's no space in the between - no trailing space at the end. But if <%# Eval("Location")%> next line <%# Eval("Location2")%>, there's a trailing space at the end for both. The system or that window to enter the code must have added it and it's strange that it does that.

Comment: Please paste your transformation code in the example to help us figure out any defects in Syntax.

Comment: @probrandono - Trim function removes all leading and trailing occurrences of characters from the string. We all have TrimStart and TrimEnd methods separately.

Comment: **Careful** when using `ToString` or `Eval<string>`. If your field (in this case `Location`) contains `NULL`, you'll get a null reference exception if you try to `Trim` it. Safest way is to use `ValidationHelper.GetString(Eval("Location"), "")`

Comment: HTML does not differentiate between a new line and a space, whenever you use one or more "whitespace characters", it interprets it as a single space (unless placed in "pre" tag), so you having each Eval at a separate line equals to having a space between them. Binding expressions in ASCX work the same way as they were tags, not influencing anything around them, including white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As Brandon already mentioned, the function you're looking for is `.Trim()`  This only works on strings though.  So if it's not working, you will most likely need to cast that object to a string using one of the following:

`ValidationHelper.GetString(Eval("Location"), "").Trim()`
`Eval<string>("Location").Trim()`

Comment: Thanks. I think it's not the string but it's the system. You can quickly test doing something like <%# Eval("YourTextField")%> <%# Eval("YourTextField")%>. You'll see the system added a space in the output, just like the space in between your 2 eval(). In my case, I used hard return/next line for the 2 eval() and the space is there, too. I thought it's supposed to act like regular text editor where your space doesn't translate into a space in the output. Please test and let me know - just for my sanity :)